# Javascript working on Safari but not on any other browser

Tags: javascript, css, requestanimationframe

I'm using `requestAnimationFrame` in Javascript for moving an html `div` by changing its "top" and "left" CSS properties. It works fine on Safari 7.1.2 but the `div` doesn't move a bit on Firefox, Chrome or Opera.

The crazy thing is that, on Chrome and Opera, if you drag the corner of the window (attempting to change its size) the `div` starts to move... and then immediatly stops moving when you release the mouse from the corner.

Here's the source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>exp_2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="exp_1.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="box_out" id="b1"><p id="menu_text">gallery</p></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var middle = document.querySelector("body").clientWidth / 2 - 50;
        window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
            middle = document.querySelector("body").clientWidth / 2 - 50;
        });

        var div = document.getElementById("b1");
        var angle = 0, lastTime = null;
        function animate(time)
        {
            if (lastTime != null)
                angle += (time - lastTime) * 0.0002;
            lastTime = time;
            div.style.top = (150 + Math.sin(angle) * 100) + "px";
            div.style.left = (middle + Math.cos(angle) * 100) + "px";
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's the CSS `class` and `id`s I've been using:

```
body
{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #232323;
    color: white;
}

#menu_text
{
    font-family: Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, Arial;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding-top: 2em;
}

.box_out
{
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 15px black;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 6em;
    height: 6em;
    background-color: #663300;
    -webkit-transition: 0.1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: 0.1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: 0.1s ease-out;
}

.box_out:hover
{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.4);
    -o-transform: scale(1.4);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.4);
}
```

Is `requestAnimationFrame` the problem or is there some compatibility issue with my CSS? I even tried leaving out the event listener for the `clientWidth` but the problem doesn't seem to be here.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=requestanimationframe

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/93704tw2/ seems to work fine to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your transition CSS is causing it not to run:

```
-webkit-transition: 0.1s ease-out;
-moz-transition: 0.1s ease-out;
-o-transition: 0.1s ease-out;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xs40d7dd/

I'm not familiar with requestAnimationFrame, but my guess is that it is an alternative way of transitioning (via JS instead of CSS). If you want to use the `transition` CSS I'd recommend just setting the top/left without using requestAnimationFrame.

Comment: Yes I think this is the real issue; fiddling with the frame handling code made no sense to me.

Comment: yeah, I'd bet the css is conflicting with the js method

Answer (score 0):

It works better in Firefox if you run it on every *other* animation frame:

```
    var div = document.getElementById("b1");
    var angle = 0, lastTime = null, toggle = false;
    function animate(time)
    {
        toggle = !toggle;
        if (!toggle) {
          var oldangle = angle;
          if (lastTime != null)
            angle += (time - lastTime) * 0.0002;
          lastTime = time;
          div.style.top = (150 + Math.sin(angle) * 100) + "px";
          div.style.left = (middle + Math.cos(angle) * 100) + "px";
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

Comment: You're right, it works! But could you explain me the relation between the "toggle" variable you used and RequestAnimationFrame? Thank you.

Comment: @George well I was just experimenting, trying to figure out why successive animation frames didn't seem to be doing anything. This was basically just an experiment; the CSS transition seems to have been the real issue.

Answer (score 0):

A helpful tool to forget about vendor prefixes:

https://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/

Extremely helpful, just call the script, no need for `-o -moz -webkit`